# Aggregator is slow when using a complex intermediate type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I have a custom `Aggregator` that does a count-min sketch aggregation. It works, but is slow (code below). I get similar slow performance if I use a custom UDAF based on the `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` class.

This is much faster if I use the `Dataset` `mapPartitions` API to aggregate within a partition and then reduce across partitions.

Question - the slowness of the UDAF and `Aggregator` APIs seem to be caused by the serialization/deserialization (encoding) that happens at each row. Are the UDAF and Aggregator APIs not meant to be used to aggregate into non-trivial data structures like the count-min sketch? Is the mapPartitions approach the best way to handle this?

`Aggregator` sample code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Row, SparkSession}
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.util.sketch.CountMinSketch

object AggTest extends App {

  val input = "2008.csv"

  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("tester")
  val sqlContext = SparkSession.builder().config(conf).getOrCreate().sqlContext

  val df = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load(input)

  implicit val sketchEncoder = org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders.kryo[CountMinSketch]

  case class SketchAgg(col: String) extends Aggregator[Row, CountMinSketch, CountMinSketch] {
    def zero: CountMinSketch = CountMinSketch.create(500, 4, 2429)

    def reduce(sketch: CountMinSketch, row: Row) = {
      val a = row.getAs[Any](col)
      sketch.add(a)
      sketch
    }

    def merge(sketch1: CountMinSketch, sketch2: CountMinSketch) = {
      sketch1.mergeInPlace(sketch2)
    }

    def finish(sketch: CountMinSketch) = sketch

    def bufferEncoder: Encoder[CountMinSketch] = sketchEncoder

    def outputEncoder: Encoder[CountMinSketch] = sketchEncoder
  }

  val sketch = df.agg(SketchAgg("ArrDelay")
              .toColumn
              .alias("sketch"))
              .select("sketch")
              .as[CountMinSketch]
              .first()

}
```

Comment: Not terribly helpful but some searching led to https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/16383 https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18980 in spark 2.2.0 which should improve this by not de/serializing the buffer object for each row.